# CSS Transition ( Vertical Cascading Menu)

Tags: html, css, menu

I've wanted to replace the letter menu (left hand side) that I have in my [personal web site](http://aljones.us/) for quite a while. I went looking for a decent accordion style menu and found [this one](http://designshack.net/articles/css/verticalaccordionav/) that looked like it would be fairly easy to implement and do what I wanted.
Changed things around a bit so that the menu, by itself, looks [like this](http://aljones.us/cascade).
Okay, so far so good. Until I try to drop it into my existing development [web pages](http://aljones.us/trial) where it only basically resembles the 'stand alone' menu.
I've looked for conflicts in the CSS - but not being good at it, I found none. Can any of you gurus offer some pointers for me.
My apologies for including the links, but that was the best way, I think, to show what's happening.
I see that others have used the same basic menu but can't find anything resembling what I'm seeing.
//al
(edited this to remove two words - grammar!)

Answer (score 0):

Your menu is embedded within:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="menu-item" id="menu-item-4">
...
```

Your #container style creates padding space:

```
#container {
    padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
}
```

Putting it under the nav style like in your example of the menu by itself should solve the problem:

```
<nav>
    <div class="menu-item" id="menu-item-4">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe on the first site demo, the author used a reset margin and padding to 0 to all elements, using the `*` selector, like so: `* {margin: 0; padding: 0}`, I think you're missing that in your css, for the following:

```
.menu-item ul, .menu-item h4{
    margin: 0;
}
```

AND also your `#container` has a padding on the left side, I don't know if its something you wanted, but if you want to make it like in the demo site, you could just remove it:

```
#container{
    padding-left: 0;
}
```